# Data binding: property of model object changes from integer to string

Tags: ember.js

In my app a model object `myModelObject` with a property `foo` is created. Initially `foo` is set to an integer. `foo` can be modified in an input form field.

Modifying `foo` in this form field to be some other integer results in `foo` changing to be a string.

- Example w/o  Ember Data: http://jsbin.com/qahafapixebe/3/edit
- Example with Ember Data: http://jsbin.com/nujesovugudo/2/edit

Is there a way to ensure that a property stays an integer after being modified via form field?

Note: `App.myModelObject.set("foo", 23)` results in `foo` staying an integer.

I use Ember 1.7.0.

Comment: is `myModelObject` of the type `DS.Model` or `Ember.Object`? or another type?

Comment: I tried both. `App.MyModelClass = DS.Model.extend({ foo: DS.attr("number", { defaultValue: 7 }) }); App.myModelObject = App.MyModelClass.create();` ...did not work for me.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think you're using the correct API. I may be wrong, but `Model` doesn't have a public `create` method. Try `store.createRecord('myModelClass', { / attributes / });`. Have you checked the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/creating-and-deleting-records/) about this? Also, can you add your code to JSBin or JSFiddle so we can take a look?

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/#toc_creating-instances

Comment: I just added a jsbin.

Comment: I just added another jsbin where i used Ember Data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the `<input type="range">` control's `value` property is a string.  To quote [the W3C wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/range):

> The range state represents a control for setting the element's value to a string representing a number.

I don't believe you will get past that fundamental constraint of the browser.

Secondly, your question is about how to enforce the value to be a `Number`.  You could do it this way:

```
App.NumericInputComponent = Ember.TextField.extend({
  init: function() {
    this.set('value', this.get('numericValue'));
    this._super();
  },
  numericValue: 0,
  updateNumeric: function() {
    this.set('numericValue', Number(this.get('value')));
  }.observes('value'),
  updateValue: function() {
    var val= Number(this.get('numericValue'));
    this.set('value', Number.isNaN(val)?null:val);
  }.observes('numericValue')
});
```

In your template, use the component:

```
{{numeric-input type="range" numericValue=myValue min="0" max="100"}}
```

See the following jsbin: http://jsbin.com/vuhunesovono/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you - looks great! :)

`numericValue: 0` is optional, isn't it? It prevents me from setting a default value for `foo` in my `App.MyModelClass`, doesn't it. I removed it and now it seems to work great. Any objections to removing  `numericValue: 0`?

Comment: No, it doesn't prevent setting the value.  As you can see in the jsbin, it is initialized with the value 12.  Initializing is handled by the `init` method.  The initial value in the component is a default if not provided

Comment: I think i could simplify your jsbin: http://jsbin.com/vuhunesovono/6/edit - i removed the `type` and `numericValue` properties in the NumericInputComponent. What do you think?

Comment: Sure, that seems to work fine.  Like I said, it is just to give some default values in case the user does not supply them.