# Ember.js Select resets when hidden and shown again

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember.select

I have an integer property which is bound to multiple input fields. The first one is of type `range`, the second is a `number` and the third one is an `Ember.Select` view. The fields are visible based on a conditional `{{#if visible}}`. When I move the slider and then hide the fields by setting `visible = false` and then make them visible again by setting `visible = true`, the bound value property gets reset to `null`.

Example here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zukukiloseqi/4/edit?html,js,output

In the example above, try to move the slider and then click 'Hide' and then 'Show'. Notice the bound property is reset to `null`. Also notice that if you don't touch the slider and set the bound property using solely the `Ember.Select`, everything works fine. And finally, when I omit the `Ember.Select` field completely, it also works fine.

What is going on here and how can I prevent the property from being reset?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with conversion between `Number` and `String`.  HTML `<input>` elements always store String representations of the value.  Please see this answer: [Data binding: property of model object changes from integer to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512358/data-binding-property-of-model-object-changes-from-integer-to-string/25578410#25578410)

I changed your controller as follows, and it seems to work every time (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zukukiloseqi/9/):

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    bindvalue:'10',
    visible: true,
    numbers: function() {
      var arr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i <= 64; ++i) {
        arr.push(''+i);
      }
      return arr;
}.property(),
actions:{
  test:function(){
    alert(this.get("bindvalue"));    
  },

  toggle: function() {
    this.set('visible', !this.get('visible'));
  }
}
});
```